# PHP DateInterval Jan - June and July - Dec

Tags: php, date-formatting

Trying to create a list or date interval for the past 2 years, divided into ranges of 6 months, i.e. Jan - June 2015, July - Dec 2015, Jan - June 2016 ... until today.

I have looked into DateTime and DateInterval, something like this

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2015-01-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2017-12-26' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P6M');

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $period as $dt )
    echo sprintf("%s\n", $dt->format("Y-m-d"));
```

Which gives me

```
2015-01-01
2015-07-01
2016-01-01
2016-07-01
2017-01-01
2017-07-01
```

Can't figure out how to get start and end (Jan 1 - June 30 and July 1 - Dec 31) for each period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding an interval, subtract one day from it. Use [`sub()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) and `new DateInterval('P1D')`, which indicates subtraction of one day.

```
foreach ( $period as $dt )
    echo sprintf(
        "%s %s\n",
        $dt->format("Y-m-d"),
        $dt->add($interval)
            ->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))
            ->format("Y-m-d"));
```

This outputs:

```
2015-01-01 2015-06-30
2015-07-01 2015-12-31
2016-01-01 2016-06-30
2016-07-01 2016-12-31
2017-01-01 2017-06-30
2017-07-01 2017-12-31
```

**Update:** In the comments you also asked how to indicate what half of the year the date represents. The answer is too obvious:

```
sprintf(
    "%s %s %d\n",
    $dt->format("Y-m-d"),
    $dt->add($interval)
        ->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))
        ->format("Y-m-d"),
    $dt->format("n")/6
);
```

Note `%d` and corresponding `$dt->format("n")/6`.

Output for me:

```
2015-01-01 2015-06-30 1
2015-07-01 2015-12-31 2
2016-01-01 2016-06-30 1
2016-07-01 2016-12-31 2
2017-01-01 2017-06-30 1
2017-07-01 2017-12-31 2
```

Comment: Ahh or course. Thanks a lot! Nice and clean solution.

Comment: A follow up question, if I want to indicate what half of the year each "start" belong to, i.e. "1" for Jan - Jun and "2" for Jul - Dec. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can just add the interval size '-1' for each start like this:

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2015-01-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2017-12-26' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P6M');

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$oneDay = new DateInterval("P1D");
$oneDay->invert=1; #just get the previous day as if("P-1D")
foreach ( $period as $dt ){
    echo  $dt->format("Y-m-d"); #interval start
    $dt->add($interval); #adding the interval size
    $dt->add($oneDay);   #get the last day of the cur interval
    echo "<br>";
    echo $dt->format("Y-m-d");  #interval end
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: isn't using negative `add` same as using `sub`? Moreover, `sub` calls for a more intuitive and cleaner native approach.